# Keras: multiclass classification

Tags: python, keras

I am following the examples from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) and [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/), and am totally new to Keras. It looks amazing - but I'm running into something I don't understand.

I have an 8-class classification problem. My training set has 5120 rows and 62 columns, the last column being the target variable.

My target variable is currently encoded as floats, so I convert them to integer and then to a dummy matrix for the model using to_categorical. The result is a numpy.ndarray of shape (num_samples, num_classes+1). Anyone know why?

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

dataset = np.loadtxt("train_pl.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:61] #I have 5120 rows. 
Y = (dataset[:,62]).astype(int) #class labels 1 to 8 inclusive

#print Y.shape #(5120,)
#print np.unique(Y) #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

y_binary = to_categorical(Y)

print y_binary.shape #(5120, 9) - why does this have 9 columns?
```

EDIT

The reason I didn't understand the answer given was I didn't understand that Keras was literally interpreting class labels as numbers. For example, since my classes are labelled 1 through 8, Keras look at the label '1' and says 'that's a 1 - I'll put it in the '1' position in the one-hot vector, like this: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. It does the same with '2': 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0, up to 8. That's why there's an extra column: to deal with the '0th' case, which doesn't exist in the mapping. Technically the accepted answer explained that, this just gives more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `to_categorical` converts class vector (integers **from 0** to nb_classes) to binary class matrix, for use with categorical_crossentropy as documented in [here](https://keras.io/utils/np_utils/).

Comment: In the tutorial [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) though, when defining the model, the author has 3 output units, which is the same dimensionality as the to_categorical result. I can't do that - I can't have 9 classes in my output.

Comment: you can try mapping the labels (y) to 0..7 by using `Y = Y - 1` before the training. Once you are predicting, map them back

Comment: Why is that necessary though? The tutorial has 3 output nodes, and 3 classes defined in to_categorical....

Comment: the tutorial is basically doing the same thing using `LabelEncoder` ([doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)). It basically transforms labels `(Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, Iris-virginica)` to `(0,1,2)` before they are converted to one-hot-encoding by `to_categorical`

Comment: Yes, the example has three classes as another data type, and once they've been converted to one-hot encoding, there are still three classes, not four. Since I don't have non-numerical labels, I don't think I need to worry about converting using LabelEncoder (I tried it anyway, and it gave the same result).

Comment: Well, you can create custom one-hot-encoding converter for your data if you don't like the way `to_categorical` works. Just convert `1` to `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`,  `2` to `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` etc. Easy, right?